# COM marshalling problem with modal dialog

Tags: multithreading, com, mfc, marshalling

I would like to pass a COM object created in the main thread of my C++/MFC8 program to a different thread, and leave all synchronization to COM. Using CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream works -- until the user opens a modal dialog. While the dialog is open, apparently all marshalling messages are rejected, which I sort of understand because they could wreak havoc, e.g. by re-entering the modal dialog. The thing is, one of the operations involving the thread is supposed to be triggered from a modal dialog, so if the rejection is just a safety measure, I would like to turn it off.

One hack I've tried is to make the dialog non-modal and disable the main window while it is open. Turns out disabling the main window *also* makes marshalling fail. This particularly surprises me because the window receiving the messages is not the main window but a special hidden one (as documented by Microsoft). So some code must be checking the "enabled" status of the main window explicitly. In fact, I can see the messages (WM_USER sent to that special window) arrive in the program's message loop and march on via DispatchMessage, but then I lose track of them.

So I'm wondering where they go next (only to come back disappointed). I figured AfxOleGetMessageFilter might lead me somewhere, but breakpoints in the implementation of the object it returns are not even hit. So if someone knows where to look, I would be very grateful. Of course, ideas for a workaround are also welcome. (The best I could come up with was to make the dialog non-modal and then temporarily re-enable the main window underneath. Yuk!)

(If someone wants to test this on a minimal example, I can try to come up with one, but it will not be small. Thanks in advance!)

Comment: *Very* bizarre.  Has to do something with the COM object, can't think of any other reason.

Comment: Thanks, you were very close. Someone had registered a message filter, which I did not find because he had used CoRegisterMessageFilter directly instead of the Afx calls. (OK, I probably shouldn't have said "my program" if I only know 1% of its code.)